# problem when changing a user's permission

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to change the user's permission, but whenever I use this function, nothing happens. The permission is not changed to `false`

My code:

```js
client.users.fetch(user).then((usuario) => {
 channel.updateOverwrite(usuario, {
  READ_MESSAGES: false,
 });
});
```

NOTE: If I try to use another permission like `SEND_MESSAGES`, this function works correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `READ_MESSAGES` is not a [Permission Flag](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Permissions?scrollTo=s-FLAGS). Instead use `VIEW_CHANNEL`